# Derive Department assignment from list for chosen month-year

Tags: excel, report

I need to create some kind of basic reporting in Excel.

Main issue is that the database I am gathering the data from is storing the department assignment in three columns but only stores the Start_Date of each new assignment.

so the file looks like:

```
    Pers_ID Department_ID Start_Date
    1001    01            2012-01-01
    1001    02            2013-05-01
    1001    05            2015-08-01
```

I need some kind of fomula which checks on a cell (e.g. A1 be "2013-08-01) and gives back the Department_ID for the Pers_ID at the given time.

I gave it a try on calculating the minimum difference between all dates and "A1" with an array formula but this can lead to assign a department_ID in the future as well.

Any help highly appreciated as Im struggling with it for hours without any working solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are your dates ***yyyy-mm-dd*** or ***yyyy-dd-mm*** ??

Comment: for easier usability within excel I did transform most dates into a yyyy-mm format (no date anymore). The Date in the column is a "datetime" sql server column. So yyyy-mm-dd + time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your list I've added additional records to test the formulas like so:

```
Pers_ID Department_ID Start_Date
1001    01            2012-01-01
1001    02            2013-05-01
1001    05            2015-08-01
1002    02            2012-05-01
1002    04            2013-01-01
1003    01            2016-01-01

Selection criteria
Person: 1002
Date:   2016-03-06

Intermediate Results
Begin:  <First formula below>
End:    <Second formula below>

Results
Dept.   <The last formula goes here>
```

The following assumption were made:

- You have your database sorted by `Pers_ID`
- Table header is at cell position `A1` (so your data starts in line 2)
- You write your selection criteria in two fields `B10` and `B11`

For distinguishing different `Pers_ID`'s we first have to know many records for a specifc `Pers_ID` are in your data source and at which position. As the data is sorted by `Pers_ID` we simply search for the first line of occurence:

```
MATCH(B10;A2:A7;0) // will return 4 as it's the 4th line in the range A2:A7
```

and count how often the specified `Pers_ID` occurs:

```
COUNTIF(A2:A7;B10) // will return 2
```

To simplify the resulting formula we can "cache" the results in cells `B14` and `B15`.

After that we can create a range using the `OFFSET()` function. We start at the beginning of the data set and move the range *down* based on our calculations. Pay attention to the `MATCH() - 1` as we don't have to move the range if the desired `Pers_ID` is in the first line (therefore specifying an offset of 0). With the result of `COUNTIF` we specify the height of the range:

```
OFFSET(B2;MATCH(B9;A2:A7;0)-1;0;COUNTIF(A2:A7;B9)) // without "cache"
OFFSET(B2;B14-1;0;B15) // with "cache"

OFFSET(B2;4-1;0;2) // partially evaluated
```

They both return B5:B6 as range of departments for `Pers_ID = 1002`

To select the appropriate line in the range wrap the formula with `INDEX()`:

```
INDEX(OFFSET(B2;B14-1;0;B15);<Row>;<Column>)
```

The `<Column>` to select is easy. As we didn't specify a width in the `OFFSET()` formula the range is only 1 column wide, so the column to select will be 1:

```
INDEX(OFFSET(B2;B14-1;0;B15);<Row>;1)
```

The `<Row>` is a little trickier. We need to specify the range of dates in column `C` with the same height as we did with the range of `Pers_ID`'s.
We use mainly the same formula as now, but we don't want to search the specified date in `B11` but the nearest one (which means the exact date or earlier). For this we use `SMALL()` ...

```
SMALL(OFFSET(C2;B14-1;0;B15);COUNTIF(OFFSET(C2;B14-1;0;B15);"<="&B11)) // returns 2013-01-01 (in fact it returns 41275 which is the 1st March 2013)
```

... and determine the line number in the range with an enclosing `MATCH()`:

```
MATCH(SMALL(OFFSET(C2;B14-1;0;B15);COUNTIF(OFFSET(C2;B14-1;0;B15);"<="&B11));OFFSET(C2;B14-1;0;B15);0) // returns 2
```

The whole formula is then:

```
// Without "cache"
=INDEX(OFFSET(B2;MATCH(B10;A2:A7;0)-1;0;COUNTIF(A2:A7;B10));MATCH(SMALL(OFFSET(C2;MATCH(B10;A2:A7;0)-1;0;COUNTIF(A2:A7;B10));COUNTIF(OFFSET(C2;MATCH(B10;A2:A7;0)-1;0;COUNTIF(A2:A7;B10));"<="&B11));OFFSET(C2;MATCH(B10;A2:A7;0)-1;0;COUNTIF(A2:A7;B10));0);1)

// With "cache"
=INDEX(OFFSET(B2;B14-1;0;B15);MATCH(SMALL(OFFSET(C2;B14-1;0;B15);COUNTIF(OFFSET(C2;B14-1;0;B15);"<="&B11));OFFSET(C2;B14-1;0;B15);0);1)
```

Maybe there's an easier/cleaner way to achieve this (e.g. array formulas with which I'm not very familiar with or VBA).

Comment: Sorry for the huge delay. Your solution works like a charm! I did some minor adaptions and added some VBA Code which automatically resorts the list after the ODBC refreshed to ensure no ones gonna wreck it.